# Firebase Database Reference doesn't detects the currently added node

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have encountered an interesting issue with firebase database references, it seems that, it doesn't updates in real time, or it doesn't sees the changes that I make when I'm using it in a for loop. I will try to explain it, but feel free to ask any questions if my explanation isn't clear enough.

1. When I load the page, an API gets called and it returns an array of movie objects.

[image]

2. Then, from each object, I grab the `id` and the `title` properties, and save them to the firebase realtime database, but before the save happens, I check if the actual object `title` already exists in the database, and if it does, I skip that particular movie:

   ```
   createMovieObjects(movies: Array<IMovies>) {

     const movieObj = {};

     for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {

       const movieId = movies[i].id;
       const movieTitle = movies[i].title;

       // check if movie with same title exists in firebase
       let movieRef = this.afDb.list('/movies', res => res.orderByChild('title').equalTo(movies[i].title)).valueChanges();

       movieRef.subscribe(res => {
         if (res[0]) {
           console.log('TITLE EXISTS! SKIPPING... ');
         } else if (!res[0]) {
           movieObj[movieTitle + '-' + movieId] = {
             id: movies[i].id,
             title: movies[i].title,
             slug: this.as.urlOptimizeText(movies[i].title),
           };
           this.saveMovie(movieObj);
         }
       });
     }
   }

   saveMovie(movieObj: Object) {
     this.myMovieRef.update(movieObj);
   }
   ```

Now, there are cases, when the API returns objects, that have exactly the same `title`s, but different `id`s. In that case, **I would like to skip the second object, and save only the first one** (ex: 37292). Currently, it saves both.

[image]

I think the problem is that the `movieRef` in the for loop doesn't updates in real time, or it does not sees that previously saved movie for some reason, resulting in saving the second movie with the same title (which should be skipped).

If I refresh the page, the same API gets called again, and then it detects bot movies and skips both objects, which is good... but it doesn't work with one API call. I hope that makes sense. :|

Can anyone help to solve this mystery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The term real time is a bit deceptive because it still takes a bit of time before something is stored or retreived from firebase. In your case i think your for loop is continuing before the movie has actually been saved in firebase. Is it an idea to filter out duplicates from the list before you check if they are in firebase?

Comment: Actually that is an interesting idea! I will think it through... thanks!

Comment: Btw, you were right about the loop is continuing before the movie is saved... which is causing the issue... Is there a way to wait for firebase to save a movie first, then continue to the next loop? I wanted to add, break and continue, but the problem is that where I would need to add these, are outside of the functions boundary, so they won't work.

Comment: Update is a Promise, so you can `await` it.

Comment: @Todor I don't think that is possible or wise to do. Personally i would do the following: 1. remove duplicates from the list 2. use the for loop to check if the movie is in firebase 3. if it isn't in firebase add it to an array 4. after the for loop is complete save the entire array in one go using multi-location updates.

Comment: @AndréKool Thank you for your help! Please add it as an answer, so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that writes to Firebase are asynchronous. Meaning the movie hasn't been actually written in the database yet while the loop keeps going.

To work around this problem I suggest you do the following steps:

1. Filter any duplicates from the list before you check if they exist in Firebase.
2. Use the loop to check if the movies exist in Firebase, if they don't add them to an array (don't save them in Firebase)
3. After the loop is finished use a multi-location update to save all the movies  that are in the array at once.

You can take a look at [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) for more information about multi-location updates and how to implement them.